# Is weak forcing a semantic relation?

Tags: logic, forcing

I'm vaguely recalling things from innumerable aeons ago:

A condition $p$ forces the negation $\sim\varphi$ of a sentence $\varphi$ precisely if no condition that extends $p$ forces $\varphi$.  From this it can follow that $p\Vdash \sim\sim\exists x\ \varphi(x)$ even though $p\not\Vdash \exists x\ \varphi(x)$.  Things like this seem unpleasant at first.  The fact that both $p\Vdash \varphi$ and $p\not\Vdash \psi$ can hold even though the models of $\varphi$ are precisely the models of $\psi$ is what I would mean by saying forcing is not a semantic relation: it depends on things about $\varphi$ and $\psi$ other than the meanings of $\varphi$ and $\psi$.

If I recall correctly, "$p$ weakly forces $\varphi$" means $p$ forces ${\sim\sim}\varphi$.

Is weak forcing a semantic relation in the sense that if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have the same models then a condition that forces one of them also forces the other?

Comment: You may want to prefer `\lnot` over `\sim` for negation. The spacing is less awry too.

Comment: I don't see why $p\Vdash\lnot\lnot\exists x\varphi(x)$ can occur alongside $p\not\Vdash\exists x\varphi(x)$. If the latter occurs then some extension of $p$ forces $\lnot\exists x\varphi(x)$. In particular this means that *some* extension of $p$ forces $\lnot\exists x\varphi(x)$ and therefore $p$ **cannot** force $\lnot\lnot\exists x\varphi(x)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : I'm thinking of a definition of forcing in a book I've just opened up, which has a chapter on forcing in arithmetic devoted to proving Addison's theorem: that the set of all sets definable in arithmetic is not definable in arithmetic.  To the language of arithmetic a single unary predicate symbol $G$ is adjoined.  "Conditions" are sets like $\{G(3), \sim G(8), G(20)\}$, etc.  A condition forces each of its members; and then a condition forces a disjunction iff $A\text{ of }B$ iff it forces either $A$ or $B$; it forces $\exists x \varphi(x)$ precisely if for some particular....

Comment: If you choose to use a definition in a book you've just open up, at least try and give context and/or some reference.

Comment: ......number $n$, it forces $\varphi(n)$; and finally it forces a negation precisely under the circumstances stated in my posting.  The book, Boolos & Jeffrey's _Computability and Logic_, observes that by this definition, some conditions do not force "$G(4)\text{ or }\sim G(4)$", even though that sentence must be true.  It goes on to point out that $\varnothing\Vdash \sim\sim\exists x\  G(x)$.  But there is no particular natural number $n$ such that $\varnothing\Vdash G(n)$, so, by the definition given, $\varnothing\not\Vdash\exists x\  G(x)$.

Comment: @Asaf: If we look at the syntactic definition, a particular condition $p$ cannot force $(\exists x)\phi$ unless $p$ already forces a witness for the quantifier. So it is possible that $p\not \Vdash (\exists x)\phi$ even though even generic filter does force $(\exists x)\phi$, in which case there cannot an extension of $p$ that forces $\lnot (\exists x)\phi$. In the example M. Hardy gave, using the syntactic defn., $\emptyset \lnot \Vdash (\exists x)(x \in G)$, but in any generic filter there will be at least one element. (For those who don't have it, BB&J is just talking about Cohen forcing.)

Comment: This a bit above my pay grade; but the "strong" forcing relation was [shown](https://www.ams.org/tran/2008-360-04/S0002-9947-07-04297-3/S0002-9947-07-04297-3.pdf) to essentially "coincide" with S4.2; the weak forcing relation seems to need Hubmerstone's "possibility semantics" https://escholarship.org/uc/item/0tm6b30q.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The forcing relation that Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey define is what might be called "strong forcing". This is a very concrete relation, which is easy to define in the ground model, but it does not in general respect classical logical equivalence. The logic that is preserved is an intuitionistic one (by "preserved" I mean the question of which inference rules are sound when provability is replaced by forcing).

One thing that is somewhat confusing is that many set theory books now write $\Vdash$ for the semantic relation: $p \Vdash \phi$ means that for every generic $G$ containing $p$, $M[G]$ satisfies $\phi$. This relation clearly preserves classical logic, but on its face there is no way to see that it is definable in the ground model.

To prove that, many contemporary books use some decorated notation (e.g. $\Vdash^*$ or $\Vdash_s$) to define an auxiliary relation (the one that Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey call $\Vdash$) which is obviously definable in the ground model but which does not obviously have the logical properties of the semantic forcing relation.

In any case what has to be proved is that there is some forcing relation definable in the ground model that has the property:

> If $G$ is a generic filter, then $M[G]$ satisfies a formula $\phi$ if and only if there is some condition in $G$ that forces $\phi$

In my version of BB&J this is Lemma 23.7. Their exposition is focused on one specific forcing notion, Cohen forcing, which allows them to mix the generic filter $G$ with the generic set, which they call $A$, that is obtained from the filter.  So it takes a minute to reconstruct the general results from the specialized statements of their lemmas.

You are right that you can define a "weak" forcing relation $\Vdash_w$ from the strong one $\Vdash_s$ with the rule $p \Vdash_w \phi \Leftrightarrow p\Vdash_s \lnot\lnot \phi$, and then the weak one will preserve classical logic.

The key point is that if $p \Vdash_s \lnot \lnot \phi$ then the set of $r \leq p$ that force $\phi$ is dense below $p$, and thus any generic filter that includes $p$ has to include such a $r$. Thus if an entire generic filter forces $\lnot \lnot \phi$ then that filter also forces $\phi$, even with the syntactic definition of forcing.  Similarly, it follows from the definition of $\Vdash_s$ that if $p \Vdash_s \lnot \lnot \lnot \lnot \phi$ then $p \Vdash_s \lnot \lnot \phi$, which should not be unexpected if we think of $\Vdash_s$ as having a sort of intuitionistic logic.

In books like Kunen's, the $\Vdash^*$ relation is a little different than the $\Vdash_s$ relation as defined by BB&J. Kunen's definition appeals to dense sets in the clause for $(\exists x)$, while the "strong" definition requires that a condition that forces an existential quantifier has to force a particular witness at the same time. So you can view the $\Vdash^*$ type definition as directly incorporating a double negation, which is how Kunen is able to prove $p \Vdash \phi \Leftrightarrow p \Vdash^* \phi$.

---

***Part 2***

Let $\Vdash_s$ be the strong forcing relation from BB&J. We have from BB&J:

> ***Lemma 23.7.*** If $G$ is a generic filter and $\phi$ is a sentence then $M[G]$ satisfies $\phi$ if and only if there is a $p \in G$ with $p \Vdash_s \phi$.

Now the solution to your question is essentially a little exercise using the key point I mentioned above.

> **Proposition 1.** $p \Vdash_s \lnot\lnot \phi$ if and only if for every generic $G$ containing $p$, $M[G]$ satisfies $\phi$.

For the forward direction, if $p \Vdash_s \lnot \lnot \phi$ then the set of $r \leq p$ such that $r \Vdash_s \phi$ is dense below $p$. Hence any generic filter containing $p$ will contain such an $r$, and thus $M[G]$ will satisfy $\phi$ by the lemma.

Conversely, suppose that for every generic $G$ containing $p$, $M[G]$ satisfies $\phi$. For contradiction assume there is a condition $q \leq p$ that forces $\lnot \phi$. Then there is a generic filter $G$ containing $q$ and $p$, and by the lemma we know $M[G] $ satisfies $\lnot \phi$. This is impossible by hypothesis, since $p \in G$.

Thus by the definition of $\Vdash_s$, for every $q \leq p$ there is some $r \leq q$ with $r \Vdash_s \phi$. This means the set of such $r$ is dense below $p$, which immediately implies that $p \Vdash_s \lnot \lnot \phi$.

> **Proposition 2.** If $M[G]$ satisfies $\phi \Leftrightarrow \psi$ for every generic $G$ containing $p$, then $p \Vdash_s \lnot\lnot\phi$ if and only if $p \vDash_s \lnot\lnot\psi$.

Suppose $p \Vdash_s \lnot\lnot\phi$. Then by Proposition 1, $M[G] \vDash \phi$ for every generic $G$ containing $p$. Hence $M[G] \vDash \psi$ for every generic $G$ containing $p$, by hypothesis. Applying the proposition again, $p \Vdash_s \lnot\lnot \psi$.

Comment: So, does this mean the answer to the question in my subject line is "yes"?

Comment: BTW I have the second edition of Boolos & Jeffrey, so Burgess wasn't involved yet.

Comment: The answer is yes ("Yes, you are right"). I typed it out in a new Part 2 of my answer. I have the fifth edition so I have no idea if the exposition in the second edition is similar, but hopefully they have something like what they currently call Lemma 23.7.

Comment: Would the weak forcing relation, as I defined it here, following B&J 2nd edition, be the closure of the (non-"semantic") forcing relation under......um.......semanticity?  I.e., the least extensive relation that is "semantic" and extends the forcing relation?

Comment: That seems very plausible, because classical logic should be the smallest logic that is obtained by taking the intuitionistic logic of the strong forcing relation and adding the scheme $(\lnot \lnot \phi) \to \phi$. But it would take some work for me to verify that, to check exactly which intuitionistic logic the strong forcing relation has and what you get when you add that scheme. I can't say that I know it for a fact.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Cohen used what is now called strong forcing. Its syntactic definition has the "obvious" clauses for $\land,\lor,\forall,\exists$; only the $\neg$ clause has the characteristic forcing form "$p$ forces $\neg\phi$ iff no extension of $p$ forces $\phi$." Weak forcing, now often just called forcing, has the same clauses for $\land,\forall,\neg$ but treats $\lor,\exists$ as defined symbols. So, for example, $p$ forces $\phi\lor\psi$ iff every extension of $p$ has a further extension forcing at least one of $\phi,\psi$.