# Why does forcing not obey some simple rules of Propositional Calculus?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, forcing

In Cohen "Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis" Cohen states on page 118:

"Also forcing does not obey some simple rules of the propositional calculus. Thus p may force $\neg \neg A$ and yet not force A".

**Question : Can anyone help me understand why this occurs, maybe by providing an example (and / or a reference where the reasoning is detailed)?**

Comment: This is not true for the modern definition of forcing.  Cohen's original definition was a bit different, I believe.

Comment: Kunen and Cohen both 'appear (to me !)' to have the same definition of $p \Vdash \neg \varphi$ so I'm mystified where the difference originates.

Comment: As I recall, Cohen’s basic notion of forcing is different from what’s customary now, in that forcing for conjunctions, disjunctions, and atomic sentences is not the same as in the currently common approaches. He then defines a second notion of forcing (based on the first one), which is equivalent to the modern notion. (This is by memory from nearly 50 years ago, and I haven’t verified my recollection, so I might be mistaken or partly mistaken.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this :

[Is weak forcing a semantic relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84621/is-weak-forcing-a-semantic-relation)

and the solution is in the associated comments and Carl Mummert's answer.

So based on the above post an example would be :

Assume $\text{ not true } p \Vdash A$

The Cohen forcing definition for negation is : $$ p \Vdash \neg (\neg A) \iff \forall Q \supseteq p \text{ not true } Q \Vdash \neg A \tag{1}$$

So as Cohen forcing is intended to be negation complete (Cohen Lemma 3, p119) and consistent (Cohen Lemma 1, p118) there could be a q $\supset p$ : $q \Vdash A$ (q $\nsubseteq$ p as we are assuming $\text{ not true } p \Vdash A$).

If $ \exists q \supset p : q \Vdash A$ then $\forall Q \supseteq p \text{ not true } Q \Vdash \neg A$

So using (1) $p \Vdash \neg (\neg A)$ or equivalently $p \Vdash \neg \neg A$

Comment: Ahhh, down voted. Any chance of pointing out my mistake(s) - I've gone over it several times but I can't spot an error. Any clues ? I can't learn (and that's why I am here) if I don't know why the response is down voted ! I will of course delete the answer ..... Cheers.

Comment: I had a go at revising the answer.

Comment: Yea, I got it right ! Many thanks to the Scarlet Pimpernel voter.